# How do I use Pandoc's extensions correctly?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

This is in my .md document:

```
![Step 1](Slide1.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 2](Slide2.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 3](Slide3.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 4](Slide4.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 5](Slide5.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 6](Slide6.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 7](Slide7.png){ width=100px }  
![Step 8](Slide8.png){ width=100px }
```

This is how I use Pandoc:

```
pandoc foo.md -f markdown+link_attributes -s -o foo.pdf
```

The link_attributes are completely ignored, and `{ width=100px }` appears as plaintext after every image.

What is the correct way of setting image size in Pandoc markdown?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are using the width parameter correctly. An alternative way supported by Pandoc is to use percent (`'%'`) instead of pixels (`'px'`):

```
![Step 1](Slide1.png){ width=13% }
```

Which Pandoc version are you using? Now, 2 years after your OP, the current Pandoc is v2.5. And it produces the correct result:

```
cat foo.md

  ![Step 1](Slide1.png){ width=100px }  
  ![Step 2](Slide1.png){ width=600px }  
  ![Step 3](Slide1.png){ width=66% }
```

No need even to specify *`-f markdown+link_attributes -s`*:

```
pandoc         \
    -o foo.pdf \
    foo.md
```

This is a screenshot from the result:

[image]